# Not getting results from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to get results from mongodb using(mongoose) the below query.

```
RolesModel.findOne({ role: 'reviewer' }, function (err, role) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send("Error getting data of reviewers");
            console.log(role._id);
            UserModel.find({ roles: role._id }, function (err, reviewers) {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send("Error getting reviewers from user table");
                res.send(reviewers);
            });
        });
```

its not returning any values. User schema is as follows:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
id: String,
//some other fields
roles: Array
}, { collection: 'conf_user' });
```

currently I have data like this.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57c2fa7156c1f6291d373227"), "roles" : [ "57c2fa6583b7bf0c1d452877" ], "__v" : 0 }
```

`"57c2fa6583b7bf0c1d452877"` this id is from "roles" table.

If i put, `UserModel.find({ roles: '57c2fa6583b7bf0c1d452877'}` then it will return me values.

Not sure what I am missing here. I have tried this also

```
{ roles: { $elemMatch: { roles: role._id } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`role._id` will return an id of type `ObjectId`, but roles are stored in the form of array of StringIds. Convert the ObjectId to string value using `role._id.toString()` before you pass the `role._id` to `UserModel.find`

```
RolesModel.findOne({ role: 'reviewer' }, function (err, role) {
    if (err) 
        return res.status(500).send("Error getting data of reviewers");
        UserModel.find({ roles: role._id.toString() }, function (err, reviewers) {
            if (err) 
                return res.status(500).send("Error getting reviewers from user table");
            res.send(reviewers);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has solved my problem :) I was doing stupid mistake.